# Transformer parallelization during training

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, transformer

What does it mean that the decoder can be parallelized during training?

Let's assume a transformer (with both encoder and decoder) is employed for a time-series prediction. I.e. from the input sequence `x_0, ..., x_N` we want to predict `y_0, ..., y_N`. Is this the way that parallelization occurs during training?

- form the batch `[], [y_0], ..., [y_0, ..., y_N-1]`
- feed this batch to the transformer, together with the input sequence
- we will obtain the batch `Y_0, Y_1, ..., Y_N`
- compare against `y_0, ..., y_N` and form the loss (*)

(*) here, some teacher ratio techiques may be employed, so that more passes may be required

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the decoder in a transformer model be parallelized like the encoder?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/12490/can-the-decoder-in-a-transformer-model-be-parallelized-like-the-encoder)

Comment: In fact no, I asked my question after reading that post. @Minh-LongLuu